# Angular2 - Dependency injection not working when injected into a dynamic component of cyclic reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a situation where based on the input selected (radio or checkbox), I add a component dynamically through ajax.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/uvGo3RxCkUPeuknVu9m8?p=preview

I explain the flow for better understanding:

First Layer: `src/parent/parent.ts`

We get the json response from questions.json and populate the questions.

Based on the `controlType` we load either `a-component` or `b-component` in `src/parent/parent.html`.

When I select a checkbox in `a-component` or a radio button in `b-component`, I call `createDynamicComponent()` and pass in the `componentData`.

`componentData` is nothing but the metadata information on the next component that needs to be populated, based on the selected option.

Now, the `componentData` is passed into the `dynamic-component` from `src/controls/a.html` or `src/controls/b.html`

Inside `dynamic-component`, I resolve the provider and inject the `questions` data into the entryComponents, (`a-component` and `b-component`)

Everything was working fine, until I introduced a `HService` (which holds the component data building logic) inside both `a-component` and `b-component`.

I am getting the following error, `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], ?)`

The last parameter being the `HService` inside the constructor of `b-component`, If I take out the service and use the commented code, everything works fine.

```js
this.componentData = {
  'questions': {
    "question": "This is a " + this.level + " level question?",
    "controlType": "radio",
    "answers": [
        "Yes",
        "No",
        "None"
    ]
  },
  "component": BComponent,
  "level": this.level
};
```

**Edit 1:** I have the `HService` injected into `a-component` already and there is no provider resolve error and it is working fine. Only on adding it to `b-component`, I face the error.

Help will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is based on circular dependencies.

`A <=> HService` and `B <=> HService`

To solve it i would unleash dependencies by creating abstract class for `HService` and use it as token:

**base.h.ts**

```
export abstract class BaseHService {
    private componentData: any;

    abstract getComponentData(queries: IQ[], level: number): any;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [ 
  { provide: BaseHService, useClass: HService }, <== this line
  { provide: 'questions', useValue: {} }, 
  { provide: 'level', useValue: 1 }
],
```

**a.ts**

```
import { BaseHService } from "../h/base.h";
...
constructor(...private _h: BaseHService) {
```

**b.ts**

```
import { BaseHService } from "../h/base.h";
...
constructor(...private _h: BaseHService) {
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jqHOypPi6oVvzqpSzPGk?p=preview)**

Comment: Nice catch but do you think this is a good pattern to follow? I mean a component creating a dynamic component in itself with the same type.. recursively adding it to itself.. mind.. blown. The dynamic component injection part should be seperated in a service in my opinion but not sure.

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the solution. It is working great. So much to understand and learn in Angular2

Comment: @echonax I am thinking of making the dynamic component injection part into a service. Will look into it.