# angular 2 re-render parent component from @ViewChild Component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am working on angular2 application where I have parent component that pops up a child component

```
@ViewChild(childPopupComponent) case: childPopupComponent;
```

What I want to do is: when pressing save button from the child component (which is popup inside the parent component), re-render the parent one for reflection to take place (instead of reloading the whole page).

I know that this re-render the current component, but how to do that from the 
    `@ViewChild` one

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your child component like:

```typescript
export class childPopupComponent {
    constructor(public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and after that you will be able to run change detection cycly only on child component:

```typescript
@ViewChild(childPopupComponent) case: childPopupComponent;

this.case.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

For updating parent you can inject it in child

```typescript
export class childPopupComponent {
    constructor(public parent: ParentComponent) {}
```

and then

```typescript
this.parent.cdRef.detectChanges()
```

or even try this:

```typescript
import { ChangeDetectorRef, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

export class childPopupComponent {
    constructor(@SkipSelf() private parentCdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Comment: Really thank you, and If I wanted to inject the whole parent component inside the child in order to call a parent function from the child.. how can I do that as It throws strange error 

    Can't resolve all parameters for casesPopupComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)

Comment: `?` usually happens with circular dependency. You can provide abstract class to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198098/angular2-dependency-injection-not-working-when-injected-into-a-dynamic-compone/43198716#43198716

Comment: Another solution for you is having @Ouput events on your child component and within parent template just subscrive to it `<child (somethingChanged)="onHandleWithParentMethod()"` This way you do not need to solve problem with circular dependency

Comment: Thank you yurzui, very useful